# Intermittent mouse connection drop Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS 9370

Tags: 18.04, mouse, bluetooth, dell

I've been using a Logitech M720 on my Dell XPS 9370. It has Ubuntu 18.04.1LTS installed.

Before a certain date, the mouse worked fine over Bluetooth. After a recent update (I can't remember which one). Now, the mouse works fine one moment, but is completely unresponsive a moment later. These periods of working/non-working are about equally long, say 10 seconds. I haven't tried any other Bluetooth device with the pc yet, but in Windows (it's dual boot) the mouse works fine.

I tried updating/upgrading to all the newest packages on the system using

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The output "dmesg | grep Blue" is the following:

```
[    6.095068] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.095079] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.095082] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.095083] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.095086] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.241043] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
```

Using;

```
sudo hcidump -x -i hciX
```

, I can monitor the events of the mouse while it's working. While the mouse is not responding no messages are coming in. These logs are pretty long, so not sure if I should post it too.

Any help is much appreciated!

edit, output of bluetoothctl:

```
[NEW] Controller 9C:B6:D0:89:9E:BC myhostname-XPS-13-9370 [default]
[NEW] Device EA:5B:72:FC:28:28 M720 Triathlon
[NEW] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service003e
    00010000-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service003e/char003f
    00010001-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service003e/char003f/desc0041
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service000c
    0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Device Information
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service000c/char0019
    00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    PnP ID
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service000c/char0017
    00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Software Revision String
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service000c/char0015
    00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Firmware Revision String
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service000c/char0013
    00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Hardware Revision String
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service000c/char0011
    00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Serial Number String
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service000c/char000f
    00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Model Number String
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service000c/char000d
    00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Manufacturer Name String
[NEW] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service0008
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Generic Attribute Profile
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service0008/char0009
    00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Service Changed
[NEW] Descriptor
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_EA_5B_72_FC_28_28/service0008/char0009/desc000b
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Device 40:4E:36:A1:DD:42 HTC BS 428FB3
Agent registered
[CHG] Device EA:5B:72:FC:28:28 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device EA:5B:72:FC:28:28 Connected: no
[CHG] Device EA:5B:72:FC:28:28 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device EA:5B:72:FC:28:28 ServicesResolved: yes
[M720 Triathlon]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has similar problems, I installed TLP power management without any configuration from my side. Disabling power saving for Bluetooth devices in TLP fixed the problem.

Comment: You understood wrong. I installed `tlp`, which caused the problems. I don't advise installing it if you start encountering similar problems.